# Variadic function and copy pasting these parameters (like we can in a macro)

Tags: c++, constructor, variadic-functions

I want a variadic function and copy-paste these parameters inside the code, like in a macro. In a macro we would simply put `__VA_ARGS__` where we want them to be copy-pasted.

Actually, I want these parameters to be values for variables, which then will be put in an object declaration (calling constructor using these values).

Look:

```
struct Object {
    std::string name;
    int id;

    Object(std::string name, int id) {
        this->name = name;
        this->id = id;
    }

};

void create(...) {
    Object object(VA_ARGS);
}

int main() {
    create("Object1", 1);
}
```

Of course that in this code nothing really happens, as the object goes out of scope, but it's just to show what I mean.

Any way to do this?

Comment: You're using c-style variadic arguments, which are a runtime construct that is very unsafe to use and very limited. You really should prefer to use [variadic templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template) for this instead of C-style variadic functions. Could you also explain what you need this for? Your code only shows one call to the `create` function; it would help to see more examples of calls that you want to make..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way of doing this in C++ is by using [*variadic templates*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template), which are a language construct that allow you to manipulate parameter packs. E.g.

```
template <typename... Ts>
Object createObject(Ts&&... xs)
{
    return Object{std::forward<Ts>(xs)...};
}

createObject(1, 'a'); // as if `Object{1, 'a'}`
```